# trying to add hyperlink to image

Tags: javascript

i'm new to javascript so please forgive my ignornace.  i have several images which i can randomly change with every refresh of the page. i need to add a hyperlink to each image but can't figure how. here's the code i'm using for each image.
In head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
MyImages=new Array();
MyImages[0]='images/1.jpg';
MyImages[1]='images/2.jpg';
MyImages[2]='images/3.jpg';
MyImages[3]='images/4.jpg';

function refresh()
{
document.getElementById("gloria").setAttribute("src", MyImages[Math.round(Math.random()*3)])
}
</script>
```

In body:

```
<body onload="refresh()"><img id="gloria"/>
```

cheers.
mike.

Comment: Where do you want to add the hyperlink? *Around* the image, after it, before it (in the DOM), somewhere else entirely? Please note: we're (generally) willing to help, but you need to take a moment to clarify your question to explain to us precisely what outcome you want and expect. And, if possible, show us your attempts to implement this desired outcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "add a hyperlink to image"? Do you mean to make the image itself clickable and when clicked go to another webpage? Or do you just want a textual hyperlink overlayed on top? Or do you want a `<map>` element for visually polygonal links?

Comment: do something like imagearray: [
        ["images/1.jpg", "yourlink", "Your text goes here"],
      ["images/2.jpg", "yourlink", "Your text goes here"],
       ["images/3.jpg", "yourlink", "Your text goes here"]
    ]     let me know if it is not working

Answer (score 0):

To wrap the image with a hyperlink:

```
function refresh()
{
    // we'll be using this element multiple times,
    // so caching it here to prevent multiple searches:
    var gloria = document.getElementById("gloria"),
    // we'll be using this twice, and it's a random-number,
    // so again: we're caching it:
        source = MyImages[Math.round(Math.random()*3)],
    // creating an <a> element:
        link = document.createElement('a');

    // setting the 'src' property of the <img />:    
    gloria.src = source;
    // setting the 'href' property of the created-<a>:
    link.href = source;

    // inserting the created-<a> element before
    // the <img /> element:
    gloria.parentNode.insertBefore(link, gloria);

    // adding the <img /> element to the appended-<a>:
    link.appendChild(gloria);
}
```

To insert the link before the image:

```
function refresh()
{
    var gloria = document.getElementById("gloria"),
        source = MyImages[Math.round(Math.random()*3)],
        link = document.createElement('a');

    gloria.src = source;
    link.href = source;

    // everything as above, but in this case (because
    // the <a> is inserted before the <img />) we add
    // some text to the <a> element:
    link.textContent = source;
    gloria.parentNode.insertBefore(link, gloria);
}
```

To insert the link after the image:

```
function refresh()
{
    var gloria = document.getElementById("gloria"),
        source = MyImages[Math.round(Math.random()*3)],
        link = document.createElement('a');

    gloria.src = source;
    link.href = source;
    gloria.parentNode.insertBefore(link, gloria.nextSibling);
    link.appendChild(gloria);
}
```

If you want to add text other than the `src` of the `<img />`, store the image-urls in an array of objects along with some relevant text, for example:

```
var MyImages = [{
    'src' : 'path/to/image1.png',
    'title' : 'This is image one'
}, {
    'src' : 'path/to/image2.png',
    'title' : 'And this is image two'
}];

function refresh()
{
    var gloria = document.getElementById("gloria"),
    // caching the object (rather than a string):
        source = MyImages[Math.round(Math.random()*3)],
        link = document.createElement('a');

    // accessing the 'src' property of the object:
    gloria.src = source.src;
    link.href = source.src;

    // everything as above, but in this case (because
    // the <a> is inserted before the <img />) we add
    // the relevant text to the <a> element:
    link.textContent = source.title;
    gloria.parentNode.insertBefore(link, gloria);
}
```

References:

- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).